# SQL Server nchar column data equality

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange problem. In my SQL Server database there is table containing an `nchar(8)` column. I have inserted several rows into it with different Unicode data for `nchar(8)` column.

Now when I fire a query like this

```
select * 
from table 
where nacharColumnName = N'㜲㤵㠱㠷㔳'
```

It gives me a row which contains 㤱㔱㄰〴㐰' as unicode data for `nchar(8)` column.

How does SQL Server compare unicode data?

Comment: It uses a collation sequence.This has nothing to do with C++ or ODBC.

Comment: Try with COLLATION `Chinese_PRC_CI_AS` (simplified) or  `Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS` (traditional) (possibly `Chinese_Hong_Kong_Stroke_90_CI_AS` depending). That is of course for Chinese (I can't read it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your column (or entire database) collation, so that equality and `like` operators work as expected. Simplified Chinese of whatever